# Misuse of guard statement to replace nil checking

Tags: swift, linked-list, swift2, switch-statement, guard-statement

I'm doing something really simple just to get used to Swift (coming from objc) - I want to return a desired node in a linked list by using a `guard` statement and a `switch` statement. I'm obviously misusing the `guard` statement because my `else` clause is huge (it's where my switch statement is being kept). Perhaps I don't even need a `switch` statement, but it just cleans things up a bit.

My old code is as follows:

```
func getValue (atIndex index: Int) -> T {
    if count < index || index < 0 {
        print ("index is outside of possible range")
    }
    var root = self.head
    //        if var root = self.head {
    if index == 0 {
        return (self.head?.value)!
    }
    if index == count-1 {
        return (self.tail?.value)!
    }
    else {
        for _ in 0...index-1 {
            root = root!.next!
        }
    }
    return root!.value
}
```

Replaced with a `guard` statement (but getting a compiler error that the guard body may not fall through) - my problem is what to return, since my function return type is `<T>` (any type).

```
func getValue (atIndex index: Int) -> T {
    guard  (count < index || index < 0) else {
        switch true {
        case index == 0:
            if let head = self.head {
                return head.value
            }
        case index == count-1:
            if let tail = self.tail {
                return tail.value
            }
        default:
            if var currentNode = head {
                for _ in 0...index-1 {
                    currentNode = currentNode.next!
                }
                return currentNode.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to add a `print` statement outside of my `guard` statement saying that the desired index is outside of the range, but I also need to return something at the end of the function of type `T`. The problem is that outside of my `guard` and switch statement, I have nothing to return.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the usage of guards. The condition that you put in the guard is the condition for *success*. The stuff you place in the body of the guard is the code to execute upon *failure*, which must lead to a transfer of control (`return`, `throw` etc). Therefore the success code should come just after the guard. Also switching over `true` makes no sense, surely switching over `index` would make more sense since that's what you're comparing? Also what's `T`? Your function isn't generic, is it a class generic?

Comment: When I tried switching over index, I was met with the error message "expression pattern of type 'Bool' cannot match values of type 'Int'". The Linked List class is generic - when instantiating, I specify what type of object I want each node value to be.

Comment: You need to use the possible values of your `index` as the cases, i.e `case 0`, `case count-1`.

Comment: You should accept CharlesA's answer, but a few unrelated observations: First, `getValue` would appear to be retrieving an item from a linked list. Rather than fixing the name to conform to standards (like CharlesA did, renaming it to `getValueAtIndex`), I'd just make it a `subscript`. Second, `switch true {...}` is redundant. I'd actually lose the `if` statements and use meaningful `case` values in `switch index { ... }`. Third, you have some paths in your code where you don't return value. For example, see https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/4286f243169b1394f0f31d4659a03e5b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `guard` statement is used to catch the invalid case, so you'd want something like:

```
func getValueAtIndex(index: Int) -> T {
    guard index >= 0 && index < count else {
        // Invalid case
        print("Index is outside of possible range")

        // Guard must return control or call a noreturn function.
        // A better choice than the call to fatalError might be
        // to change the function to allow for throwing an exception or returning nil.
        fatalError("Index out of bounds")
    }

    // Valid cases
}
```

Comment: A plain `return` will not compile here because the function has a (non-void) return type.

Comment: @MartinR Good point, switched it to fatalError and added a note.

Answer (score 0):

A `guard` statement is meant to move the program out of its current scope or call a `noreturn` function if a value is found to be `nil`. You however, are running an entire `switch` statement in your `guard`.

As per [Apple's Guard Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/guard-statement):

> The `else` clause of a `guard` statement is required, and must either call a function marked with the `noreturn` attribute or transfer program control outside the guard statement’s enclosing scope using one of the following statements:
>
> - return
> - break
> - continue
> - throw

A good example of a `guard` might be:

```
var optValue : String?

guard let optValue = optValue else {return}
```